# Artifact 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.1:gradle.jar' not found on Android Studio 0.8.1

Tags: android, gradle

I've upgraded to Android Studio 0.8.1 and when I try to compile any app it fails with the following error:

```
Error:Artifact 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.1:gradle.jar' not found on Android Studio 0.8.1
```

I tried to update manually the plugin from gradle.org and it does not contain any gradle.jar binary.

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
Shutdown Android Studio
Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
Restart Android Studio let it download all the Gradle stuff it needs
Gradle build success !
Rebuild project.... success !

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies
```

It worked for me =)

Comment: Thank you so much!  This resolved my issue.  You rock, Helio! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this to the build.gradle file?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
```

It should download the file from the maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project directory and edit ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties update the version number and then go to Tools -> Android -> Synch Project with Gradle Files.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like gradle:0.12.1 is the problem, I just changed the "+" with "0" and it worked for me.

file: build.gradle from the root of project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```